# After upload the Andriod app to APkPure the system keeps show Error 10003 In

Tags: app-store, apk, appstore-approval

I uploaded a test app to APkPure. After the upload and refresh the page APkPure shows this error message with no other description :
"The version your uploaded didn't pass the upload verification. Error 10003. Please try again."
I tried many times with no luck. Does anyone know what this error means?

Comment: I'm having the same problem so I'll be watching this.

Answer (score 4):

The **package name** of your apk is different from the **package name** you typed on APkPure.
Try and have a uniform **package name**. Ave Maria.

Answer (score 0):

In your file manifest of the app you watch

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="name_package">`

you must copy "name_package" and to place in apkpure.